# How to limit return result on Crystal 2011 with DB2 server?

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, db2

and thanks in advance!

I am using crystal reports 11 and my database is DB2! 
I have a report that pulls the number of trailers per customer zone; however some customers are only responsible for one trailer.
is there a way to use "fetch first row only" within the formula fields?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to view only one trailer then you can use `sql expression fields`.

Syntax would be

```
(Select trailer from table where customer database field=customer name  fetch first row only)
```

Place the field on report